# Find eigenvalues of $T$ if $T(w,z)=(z,w)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the eigenvalues of the above Transformation.  Is it as easy as recognizing that the matrix of $T$, $M(T)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\\\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Without resorting to the matrix, what number $\lambda$ gives you $T(w,z) = \lambda (z,w)$

Comment: The eigenvalues of the transformation are the same eigenvalues of the matrix of the transformation (in any basis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $T(w,z) = \lambda(z,w)$. Forgetting that $\lambda = 0$ or any trivial solutions, you have the following equations

$$z = \lambda w  $$ and $$w = \lambda z.$$

Upon substituting the first equation into the second gives $$w = \lambda^2 w$$

Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the matrix representation, but you don't have to.

What do you notice about $T(1,1)$ and $T(1,-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is real and $T^2 x = x$, we see that $T$ is normal, and if $T x = \lambda x$, you must have $\lambda^2 = 1$, hence $\lambda \in \{-1,+1\}$.

They cannot be the same, otherwise $T$ would be a multiple of the identity (since $T$ is normal and can be diagonalized by its eigenvectors), hence they must be $\pm 1$.